# How to gracefully exit SLIME and Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, dot-emacs, slime

I have a question regarding how to "gracefully exit SLIME", when I quit Emacs. Here is the relevant portion of my config file:

```
;; SLIME configuration

(setq inferior-lisp-program "/usr/local/bin/sbcl")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/Scripts/slime/")
(require 'slime)
(slime-setup)

;; configure SLIME to gracefully quit when emacs
;; terminates

(defun slime-smart-quit ()
  (interactive)
  (when (slime-connected-p)
    (if (equal (slime-machine-instance) "Gregory-Gelfonds-MacBook-Pro.local")
 (slime-quit-lisp)
      (slime-disconnect)))
  (slime-kill-all-buffers))

(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook 'slime-smart-quit)
```

To my knowledge this should automatically kill SLIME and it's associated processes whenever I exit Emacs. However, every time I exit, I still get the prompt:

```
Proc       Status   Buffer  Command
----       ------   ------  -------
SLIME Lisp    open      *cl-connection* (network stream connection to 127.0.0.1)
inferior-lisp run      *inferior-lisp* /usr/local/bin/sbcl


Active processes exist; kill them and exit anyway? (yes or no)
```

Can someone shed some insight as to what I'm missing from my config?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Who cares about shortcut keys? We want something to paste into .emacs that quits SLIME when emacs ends.

Answer (score 26):

I know it's not exactly what you asked for, but maybe this will be helpful to other noobs like me.

You can execute a *SLIME command* to exit, so you'll have a nice, clean emacs left over.

In a SLIME buffer, type in <kbd>,</kbd> (comma). You're placed in the minibuffer and SLIME asks which command to execute. Type in <kbd>sayoonara</kbd> and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You should see SLIME exiting, the minibuffer mentions that "Connection closed." and you're placed in the *scratch* buffer.

I wonder if there's some way to simply invoke this "sayoonara" command from your .emacs, as opposed to manually unwiring everything.

Comment: I prefer 'quit' to 'sayoonara'. It's shorter :-)

Comment: This terminates my stumpwm session. :)  I think I only need `(slime-disconnect)`.

Comment: The function is `slime-repl-sayoonara`. There is also `slime-repl-quit`.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [manual page on this](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Killing-Emacs.html), "once save-buffers-kill-emacs is finished with all file saving and confirmation, it calls kill-emacs which runs the functions in this hook."  So the check for active processes is done before the hook is called.

A working solution would be to make your own kill-emacs command, for example

```
(defun kill-emacs-slime ()
  (interactive)
  (when (slime-connected-p)
    (if (equal (slime-machine-instance) "Gregory-Gelfonds-MacBook-Pro.local")
        (slime-quit-lisp)
      (slime-disconnect)))
  (slime-kill-all-buffers)
  (save-buffers-kill-emacs))
```

And then bind this to your quit key

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-c") 'kill-emacs-slime)
```

(I am assuming your function correctly quit SLIME and closes its buffers, I haven't tested it).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the check for active processes (and the query for confirmation to kill) would be activated before `kill-emacs-hooks` had a chance to do its job.

A very kludgy solution:

```
(defadvice save-buffers-kill-terminal (before slime-quit activate)
  (slime-smart-quit)
  (sleep-for 1))
```

The function `slime-quit-lisp` is asynchronous; it needs time to finish after returning, hence the `sleep-for`.

Answer (score 2):

One way to debug the problem is to debug the function.

Place your cursor inside the `'slime-smart-quit` routine and type <kbd>M-x edebug-defun</kbd>.  Then exit Emacs as you normally would.  You should then be prompted by the Emacs lisp debugger [edebug](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Edebug.html#Edebug).  It's a pretty easy debugger to use (type <kbd>?</kbd> for help).

Step through the code and see where it doesn't do what you expect it to do.

Use <kbd>q</kbd> to quit out of the debugger, then make changes, and <kbd>M-x edebug-defun</kbd> again to debug the new version.

Repeat until you find success, or have a little more information for the question.

Answer (score 2):

@Alex - I found your  method to be the cleanest way to quit SLIME. However the config file needs to be edited in this fashion for it to be used.

```
(require 'slime-autoloads)
(slime-setup '(slime-fancy)) ; load contrib packages
```

Once it's setup this way then:

1. press **comma (,)** to bring up the minibuffer
2. type **quit** or **sayoonara** to cleanly exit.

PS: Check this for SLIME config at startup - http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Loading-Contribs.html

Answer (score 1):

I find it annoying to have to agree to kill all processes every time I close the Emacs so I come up with this function

```
(defun emacs-forget-buffer-process ()
  "Emacs will not query about this process when killing."
  (let ((p (get-buffer-process (current-buffer))))
    (when p
      (set-process-query-on-exit-flag p nil))))
```

which makes process die silently when Emacs is closed. Use it like this

```
(add-hook 'slime-inferior-process-start-hook #'emacs-forget-buffer-process)
(add-hook 'slime-repl-mode-hook #'emacs-forget-buffer-process)
```

I use it for all repl-like buffers that I have, which includes octave, python, scheme, shell and haskell's ghci. So far nothing bad happened when these repls get killed silently so I assume this solution isn't bad though may not be graceful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more general solution that I use.
It works not just for SLIME, but for other stuff, e.g. python, terminal, lisp etc.

```
(defadvice save-buffers-kill-emacs (around no-query-kill-emacs activate)
  "Prevent annoying \"Active processes exist\" query when you quit Emacs."
  (flet ((process-list ())) ad-do-it))
```

Answer (score 0):

This took me forever. If you have two windows opened up, switch to the slime window and hit c-x 0 to kill that window. Then you can kill the emacs window normally through c-x c-c.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I feel is a better solution that specifically ignores only `SLIME` buffers. It doesn't actually kill the processes if the user aborts the `kill-emacs` command, nor does it require waiting for slime to asynchronously exit gracefully.

```
(defun process-ignore-on-exit (regexp)
  (cl-loop for proc in (process-list)
           when (s-matches-p regexp (process-name proc))
           do
           (progn (message "disabling query-on-exit for '%s'" proc)
                  (set-process-query-on-exit-flag proc nil))))

(defun slime-ignore-processes-on-exit (&rest r)
  (process-ignore-on-exit "SLIME"))

(advice-add #'save-some-buffers :before #'slime-ignore-processes-on-exit)
```

Answer (score -1):

No, no, no. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10780124/539797 ; any other way of killing a process buffer is at best rude, if not plain dangerous to children and puppies.