# Make Emacs stop asking "Active processes exist; kill them and exit anyway"

Tags: emacs

In spite of all the advice that it is a bad idea, I **still** would like Emacs to stop asking me "Active processes exist; kill them and exit anyway" when I hit C-c C-x.  I would like it to simply kill all active processes without asking.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What is the advice that it is a bad idea?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This snippet (goes into your .emacs customization file) will temporarily make Emacs believes that there is no active process when you kill it, and therefore you won't get the annoying prompt.

```
(require 'cl-lib)
(defadvice save-buffers-kill-emacs (around no-query-kill-emacs activate)
  "Prevent annoying \"Active processes exist\" query when you quit Emacs."
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function #'process-list) (lambda ())))
    ad-do-it))
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Specs: Aquamacs 23.2.50.1 / Aquamacs-SLIME-2010-11-14 / Mac OS X 10.6.4 / MacBook Pro 5,1

Comment: `flet` is really cool but unfortunately deprecated since Emacs 24.3, however Nic Ferrier has reimplemented it as `noflet` which is available through package.el. Probably best to either use that instead, or use the other solution below with hooks (on second thought, defadvice is a bit ugly to begin with, so the hooks solution is probably better generally).

Comment: I've updated this answer to use `cl-letf`, which should work with `cl-lib` and lexical binding.

Comment: In my case, I worked with GNU Emacs 26.3 on Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS.

Comment: Worked perfectly for Emacs 27.1 on Debian Testing. Many thanks!

Answer (score 19):

You can accomplish this by setting **query-on-exit** flag for each  process to nil.
You can use a hook to do this automatically when executing a command interpreter:

```
(add-hook 'comint-exec-hook 
      (lambda () (set-process-query-on-exit-flag (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)) nil)))
```

Comment: Note that the docs say (regarding process-kill-without-query) "This function is obsolete since 22.1" and recommend using set-process-query-on-exit-flag instead.

Comment: For some reason this didn't work for me with `comint-exec-hook`, using `multi-term` (the hook simply never ran). Had to switch it to `term-exec-hook` and that worked.

Answer (score 15):

The next version of Emacs (25.3 or 26.1) will have a new customization option `confirm-kill-processes` to make this simpler.  You can then say `M-x customize-variable RET confirm-kill-processes RET` and set the variable to `nil` to suppress the confirmation prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You can't without hacking.  If you are feeling adventurous, replace definition of `save-buffers-kill-emacs` in your `.emacs` so that it doesn't ask (but don't forget to repeat procedure each time you upgrade Emacs afterwards).  Standard defition of that function asks without any ways to customize that behavior.

EDIT:

Alternatively, you could redefine `yes-or-no-p` like this (untested):

```
(defadvice yes-or-no-p (around hack-exit (prompt))
   (if (string= prompt "Active processes exist; kill them and exit anyway? ")
       t
      ad-do-it))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(if (get-buffer your-process-buffer)
      (progn
    (if (get-buffer-process your-process-buffer)
        (set-process-query-on-exit-flag (get-buffer-process your-process-buffer) nil)
      (kill-buffer your-process-buffer))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I feel is a better solution that specifically ignores only `SLIME` buffers:

```
(defun process-ignore-on-exit (regexp)
  (cl-loop for proc in (process-list)
           when (s-matches-p regexp (process-name proc))
           do
           (progn (message "disabling query-on-exit for '%s'" proc)
                  (set-process-query-on-exit-flag proc nil))))

(defun slime-ignore-processes-on-exit (&rest r)
  (process-ignore-on-exit "SLIME"))

(advice-add #'save-some-buffers :before #'slime-ignore-processes-on-exit)
```

Comment: Nice solution but I had to call `save-some-buffers` manually to see an effect. I substituted it with `save-buffers-kill-terminal`, which is bound to `C-x C-c`. Is there any downside to this?

Comment: I'm not sure how you were previously exiting emacs, but that is how I normally exit emacs, by typing `C-x C-c` which is bound to `save-buffers-kill-terminal`. This internally calls `save-some-buffers` (`save-buffers-kill-terminal -> save-buffers-kill-emacs -> save-some-buffers`) which will trigger the advice.