# Automatically stopping a process when exiting Emacs

Tags: emacs, hook

I am trying to stop the simple-httpd server with its command **httpd-stop** when I type the **C-x C-c** command (save-buffers-kill-terminal to quit emacs), cause I would like to get rid of the "Active processes exist; kill them and exit anyway? (yes or no)" message every time I type C-x C-c.
To achieve my aim, I was thinking about writing a hook like:

```
(add-hook 'save-buffers-kill-terminal
                (lambda () (httpd-stop)
                    ))
```

But it did not work. I continue to get the message "Active processes exist; kill them and exit anyway? (yes or no)" when I type C-x C-c.

How can I achieve my goal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no hook named `save-buffers-kill-terminal`.

There's a function by that name, but hooks don't automatically exist for every function (the `advice` mechanism does facilitate that in effect, but you don't need that here *(edit: or maybe you do; see below)*).

A hook only exists if there is code which explicitly runs it with `run-hooks`, or similar (e.g. `C-u C-h a run.*hook RET`). Or more specifically, you can `add-hook` with any arbitrary variable, but it will never function *as* a hook unless something runs it.

In general you would use either of `kill-emacs-hook` (if the callback does not need to interact with the user), or `kill-emacs-query-functions` if interaction could be necessary. See the help of each of those variables for details.

*Edit:*

In the case of active processes, a different mechanism is needed, as these queries happen before either of those hooks are run.

If you just want to avoid the query and let the process be killed, you can use `set-process-query-on-exit-flag`. This sets a per-process flag which determines whether or not this query will happen:

```
set-process-query-on-exit-flag is a built-in function in `process.c'.

(set-process-query-on-exit-flag PROCESS FLAG)

Specify if query is needed for PROCESS when Emacs is exited.
If the second argument FLAG is non-nil, Emacs will query the user before
exiting or killing a buffer if PROCESS is running.  This function
returns FLAG.
```

You would probably arrange this when you started the process (assuming you have some code which starts httpd), obtaining `PROCESS` with either `(get-process NAME)` or `(get-buffer-process BUFFER)`. I'm not using this httpd library, so I don't know specifically what you'll need here.

If you definitely want to call a graceful shut-down function like `httpd-stop`, I think you'll need to do something custom.

```el
(defadvice save-buffers-kill-emacs (before my-httpd-auto-stop)
  (when (httpd-is-running-p) ;; not a real predicate
    (httpd-stop)))
(ad-activate 'save-buffers-kill-emacs)
```

You'll have to figure out what to use in place of my hypothetical `httpd-is-running-p`, to establish whether or not to call the stop function.

Note that this would run before any other queries, so you might stop httpd this way but then decide not to kill emacs after all (but that sort of thing is possible regardless).

*Edit:* Alternatively, as it is apparently safe to call this stop function whether or not httpd is running, you could use the following (including an added test to see whether or not `httpd-stop` is defined, as calling it will be an error otherwise, and I'm not sure how you load the library):

```el
(defadvice save-buffers-kill-emacs (before my-httpd-auto-stop)
  (when (fboundp 'httpd-stop)
    (httpd-stop)))
(ad-activate 'save-buffers-kill-emacs)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have tried this:

`(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook
 
     (lambda () (httpd-stop)
      ))`

But it did not work, how can I run automatically httpd-stop when I type C-x C-c???

Comment: Ah, tricky. The active processes query actually happens *before* either of these hooks are run. But I see there's a mechanism for this. I shall update the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, I have found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706527/make-emacs-stop-asking-active-processes-exist-kill-them-and-exit-anyway)
But I do not want to auto kill all the processes, just the simple-httpd server...

Comment: `(when (httpd-is-running-p) 
    (httpd-stop)))` -> I have changed it in this:
`(if t
    httpd-stop)))`
Cause the **httpd-stop** function does nothing if the server has  already been stopped, so it runs httpd-stop every time.
I can do something like that, can't I? I guess I can.

Comment: Sure, but the code in your comment has wrong/unbalanced parentheses, and in any case an `if` or `when` with condition `t` is fairly pointless, so just call `(httpd-stop)` on its own. Note that if this function is not autoloaded, you would either need to ensure that the library is loaded, or else instead use `(when (fboundp 'httpd-stop) (httpd-stop))` so that it only calls the function if it is defined.

Comment: Sorry phils, what does fboundp do?

Comment: Type: `C-h f fboundp RET`. The same applies for any (loaded or autoloaded) elisp function.

Comment: Thank you for your responses phils, you really help me! It works!